# How do I convert a Buffer of bytes to a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I send a string to the server using a Formdata object. I send it as a Blob since that is the format expected using Formdata. However when I receive at the server, it shows up like this. I am using node:buffer for the Buffer library

```
{"timestamp":"2023-06-14T23:07:22.697Z","message":"Buffer from Multipart buffer is  <Buffer 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 4f 62 6a 65 63 74 5d>\n"}
{"timestamp":"2023-06-14T23:07:22.697Z","message":"Data is is  [object Object]\n"}
```

I use the buffer.toString() but it outputs the following which I have no idea what it is
[object Object]. How can I get the original string back from this that I receive?

<Buffer 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 4f 62 6a 65 63 74 5d>

Answer (score 0):

The converted string of `<Buffer 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 4f 62 6a 65 63 74 5d>` is `'[object Object]'`.
When applying to `FormData`, if the data is `object`, use `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
formData.append('foo', { bar: 'dgx' }) // it will be ['foo', '[object Object]']
formData.append('foo', JSON.stringify({ bar: 'dgx' })) // it will be ['foo', '{"bar":"dgx"}']
```

Comment: I used Blob because the string data should not be translated in any way by JSON.stringify.  So I would like to retrieve the string in its original value

Comment: Also, the backend I use sends FormData as Buffers even if you send them as strings